# C# XmlSerializer conditionally serialialize List<T> items

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

i need to serialize and deserialize XML with C# XmlSerializer (or is there something better?).

```cs
[XmlElement]
public virtual List<Map> Maps { get; set; }

public class Map
{
    [XmlAttribute("item")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("uri")]
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}

Maps = new List<Map>{
    new Map { Item="", Uri="" },
    new Map { Item="something", Uri="foo" },
    new Map { Item="", Uri="foo" },
}
```

The serializer should throw out every item with string.IsNullOrEmpty(map.Item) so that the resulting Xml only holds the map with "something".
How can I achieve this without a big hassle?:

`<Maps>
     <Map item="something" uri="foo" />
</Maps>`

Comment: This is better handled by code, not serializer. So before serlializing, loop through the list and remove empty maps. And if needed, do the same after deserializing. You can create a function for that and you can make an extension method if you like.

Comment: Thanks racil - that was my thinking. just wanted to ask if there is something better / nicer

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood, you want to filter your XML before you serialize it.

I suggest you use `LINQ` for this:

`var filteredMaps = Maps.Where(map => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(map.Item)).ToList();`

Notice the `.ToList()` call at the end of the line. This is important, as your `XmlSerializer` is of type `List<Map>` I suppose. Put this line before you serialize your object and the result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Map item="something" uri="foo" />
</ArrayOfMap>
```

Don't forget the `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try creating an XmlWriter that filters out all elements with an xsi:nil attribute or containing an empty string, and passes all other calls to the underlying standard XmlWriter to "clean up" serialized XML.

Comment: That sounds interesting - i will look into that thank you!

Comment: @TimvanPeterson No problem, if you've found it useful do not hesitate to upvote comment or answer - I'm still collecting repo points here ;-)